# Operator Name Exceeded 80 characters for window()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've stumbled upon a bizarre situation. I am trying to execute this:

```
DataStream<Integer> numStream = env.fromElements(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).name("numSource");
DataStream<Integer> controlStream = env.fromElements(3,23,14,53,65,77,85,102).name("conSource"); 


JoinedStreams.WithWindow<Integer, Integer, Integer, TimeWindow> joinedStreams =
                numStream
        .join(controlStream)
        .where(numS -> numS, TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Integer>() {}))
        .equalTo(controlS -> controlS%10, TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Integer>() {}))
        .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(300)));

joinedStreams.apply(new JoinFunction<Integer, Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, Integer> join(Integer integer, Integer integer2) throws Exception {
            return Tuple2.of(integer, integer2);
        }
    }).print();

env.execute("Sandbox Job");
```

In return, I get this error back:

```
16:59:39,305 WARN  org.apache.flink.metrics.MetricGroup [] - 
The operator name Window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows(300), ProcessingTimeTrigger, CoGroupWindowFunction) 
exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.
```

I've tried to name the transformation, in vain. I've tried to change the metrics size, I couldn't find it anywhere to change it.

Any help would be very valuable, it looks very simple task and still, I cant run it.

I am appending the pom.xml properties and dependencies file below. Thank you in advance.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gr.tuc.psavvaidis</groupId>
    <artifactId>pli613_lab</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Flink Quickstart Job</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.12.0</flink.version>
        <kafka.version>2.7.0</kafka.version>
        <target.java.version>1.8</target.java.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${target.java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Apache Flink dependencies -->
        <!-- These dependencies are provided, because they should not be packaged into the JAR file. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add connector dependencies here. They must be in the default scope (compile). -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add logging framework, to produce console output when running in the IDE. -->
        <!-- These dependencies are excluded from the application JAR by default. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You're getting a warning, not an error, about the name length. Why do you say "I can't run it"?

Comment: Hey @kkrugler, when I commend it, it runs and prints as expected. but when I join and window it, I get the warning and I get no results. Flink usually gives me errors about runtime, no sinks assigned, types, not implemented interfaces, the program can still run, but it discards the job

Comment: When you add the windowing function, nothing gets emitted until the window trigger fires (300ms, in your case). But before that happens, your two sources are finished, and the workflow stops running.